# How to deal with list of goals in core.logic

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm sure this must be a stupid question, but how do I deal with a list of goals in core.logic?

```
(run* [g]
   (f))

(defn f[]
  '(succeed succeed))
```

Will throw an exception, as `run*` doesn't expect a list. I feel like I need to do `(apply all (f))`, but `all` is a macro, so that doesn't work.

What's the solution? I feel I'm missing something trivially obvious here...

Adrian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goals take only one parameter then you can use [everyg](http://clojure.github.io/core.logic/index.html#clojure.core.logic/everyg) as suggested in another answer. Basically (everyg g coll) is a goal that succeeds when the goal g succeeds on each element of coll. Therefore coll is not a collection of goal, but a collection of single parameter to g. This still helps because, combined with [project](http://clojure.github.io/core.logic/index.html#clojure.core.logic/project), this makes it possible to write:

```
(defn applyg
  [g v]
  "Goal that succeeds when the goal g applied to v succeeds.
  Non-relational as g must be ground."
  (project [g] (everyg g [v])))
```

And when there is a collection of goals to apply:

```
(defna apply-collg
  [gcoll v]
  ([() _])
  ([[gh . gt] _] (applyg gh v) (apply-collg gt v)))
```

Using [pred](http://clojure.github.io/core.logic/index.html#clojure.core.logic/pred) to make a goal out of a clojure predicate, it becomes easy to test:

```
(run* [q] (apply-collg [#(pred % pos?) #(pred % odd?)] 1))
=> (_0)
(run* [q] (apply-collg [#(pred % pos?) #(pred % odd?)] 2))
=> ()
```

If the goals to apply take 2 or more parameters then one just need to transform them into goals taking a single collection of parameters.

I'm still quite new to core.logic so comments are welcomed.

Comment: Thanks, I never was sure about my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
(everyg succeed (f))
```

I'm still interested if there is a better or at least more idiomatic solution.

Comment: There is a confusion in this answer: (everyg g coll) is a goal that succeeds when the goal g succeeds on each element of coll. So
    (everyg succeed (f))
applies the goal succeed to all values of the collection returned by the function f. The fact that f returns a collection of goals is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but looking at http://www.clojure.net/2012/10/02/More-core.logic/ there seems to be a similar thing using this construct:

```
(def f (all
         succeed
         succeed))
```

Comment: Yes, this will work - you've turned the list into a single goal. But what if your list of goals is of unknown arity? What do you do then? (in my case they are generated by a for loop).